# Actions in selenium firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I have been trying to perform the actions operation in firefox quantum version 57+ with selenium version 3.5.0 and using geckodriver 0.19.1. But the thing is it is unable to perform the click operation using Actions.

The code that I have written is :

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@title,'" + projName + "')]"));    
new Actions(driver).click(ele).perform();
```

But the thing is this line of code is not getting executed and the click operation is not performed. This code has been running in the chrome latest versrion.

Can anyone help me out here whether currently there is still implementation going out to make Actions class stable with Firefox.

Comment: Whats wrong with the powerful & proven `Java` `click()`? Any error? Can you update the Question with the error stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

`geckodriver` doesn't support `Actions` class, only the W3C WebDriver standard.

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233) it will be added some time in the future, but there isn't any ETA for this.