# Executing an event from python

Tags: python, html, selenium, events, launch

As a beginner with python I am trying to make a simple automated login project. One more thing I have to do is to mouse click on the 4th row of html table to show me proper content. The html code of that segment is:

```html
<tr class="tbl_seznam_barva_1" onclick="setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl02$ctl00$BrowseSql1\',\'Select$0\')',470);" onmouseover="radekSeznamuClass=this.className;this.className='RowMouseOver';" onmouseout="this.className=radekSeznamuClass;">
  <td>virtuálny terminál</td>
</tr>
```

How to execute this "onclick" event?

```py
from selenium import webdriver

#...

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('txtUsername')
elem.send_keys('myLogin' + Keys.RETURN)

elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]")

# some code for event execution goes here...
```

Comment: Simply call [`WebElement.click()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click)

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur I have tried it before: elem.click() doesn't work

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/polak/PycharmProjects/VESCON_login/VESCON_login.py", line 17, in <module>
    elem.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Actually your calling it on list.. you need to call it as `elems[0].click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that one should wait for webpage to fully load

After the line `elem.send_keys('myLogin' + Keys.RETURN)` the  webpage needs time to render a content, so a delay should by added:

```
import time

# ...

elem.send_keys('myLogin' + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)
elem=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]")
elem.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `click()` on the element with text as `virtuálny terminál` you can achieve it with:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='virtuálny terminál']").click()
```

If you need to click on more elements you can use a for-loop on all the elements.

```
elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]")
for i in elements:
    print(i.text)
```

## Edit:

You can use `ActionChains`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

my_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]")
action = ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element(my_elem)
# action.move_to_element_with_offset(my_elem, 5, 5)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

## Edit2:

If you can't use chromedriver and you have nothing else to do you can use `execute_script`:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: I got:
Unable to locate element: //*[text()='virtuálny terminál']

Comment: @Dounchan did you try looping through the elements?

Comment: No. We don't understand each other. I do not want to loop through. I just want to click on the 4th row of the table element. I changed `browser.find_elements_by_xpath` to `browser.find_element_by_xpath`
Actually, the xpath after clicking inspect element in firefox is `/html/body/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]`
But I think the click() function is not applicable to it, because it is not a button, form or a link.

Comment: @Dounchan ok sorry for the misunderstanding, you can try using `ActionChains` to click on that element

Comment: I got error on `action.perform()` line (click was not successful):
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindowUtils.sendMouseEvent]"

Comment: @Dounchan you should use Chrome driver instead see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399916/8179099)

Comment: @Dounchan As a last resort, you can use `execute_script` see my edit2